# Populating MySQL Table via Mutliple File Imports

Tags: mysql, bash, import

I have a MySQL table that needs periodic updating via a LOAD DATA INFILE command, which gets structured data from a .csv file. Initially I only had to do this LOAD DATA command once a week for a single .csv file, now things are picking up and I need to import data from multiple .csv files several times a week. I don't think MySQL itself has a mechanism for iterating through the contents of a directory, finding all .csv files, and then loading data from each before moving on to the next.

So I think I need some sort of command line script that iterates through all files of a given type in a given directory, passes the filename into a mySQL LOAD DATA INFILE command, waits for mySQL to finish processing that file, then moves on to the next file until all files are processed. I'd like to learn bash scripting someday, so if bash offers a good way to do this I'd like to begin using bash. Or if mySQL has a way to do this, that would be good also.

This is on a Macbook (iOS) platform.

Comment: Specify your question in a more explicitly. In you are interested in possible ways to iterate through files, besides bash-script it may be also a python script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using bash. Let's say all .csv are place in Data folder.

```
Open a terminal then go to the folder on the same level with Data
Type this "vi script.sh" to open an editor
Copy/paste below codes:

#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./Data/*.csv; do
    <use load data  using "$filename">
done

Press ESC then :
Type wq! then enter -> to save (w) and quit
Change mode of the script:   
      Type chmod 775 script.sh
Then run this script:
      sh <script.sh>.
```

It will scan all csv files under Data folder then run load data using that csv

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this as soon as possible.  I assume then that I was right in that there is no way to do this from within MySQL?

Comment: This didn't work for me as the <use load data...> SQL statement needed some extra escape characters and it got pretty confusing, such as stuff like '...ENCLOSED BY \""'""
        ESCAPED BY ""'""'.  Is there a way to write the MySQL in a separate file and then just call that file from the bash script?